# Magento 2.2 Production mode Issue

Tags: magento2, bug, production

When I enable the production mode everything works perfectly.

But when i run this command

```
php bin / magento setup: upgrade
```

All static files from `pub/static`  are automatically deleted (no .htaccess) but They are not regenerated

```
Consequently the screen appears: Unable to retrieve deployment of static files from the file system.
```

I always have to generate static files every time!!
There is a solution?

Is a magento 2.2.2 bug.

Comment: Which MODE you have set in env.php?

Comment: This is my env.php https://pastebin.com/pKzrRX3W

Comment: Set 'MAGE_MODE' => 'production' to 'MAGE_MODE' => 'developer'

Comment: use this command to set developer mode: php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

Comment: Why? I need to run my store in production mode. I found this : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6426#issuecomment-434991404

Comment: I can't figure out how to resolve with the string: static_content_on_demand_in_production

it is a particular mistake.

Files are not regenerated in production mode.

Answer (score 0):

please run this command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: Yes, will generate. But the problem is that every time when i run setup:upgrade, i need to run content deploy for all my storeview

Comment: Yes, because Magento don't deploy static content automatically in production mode instead of setup upgrade you can use `php bin:magento cache:flush`

Comment: Yes, but if i already generated static content file in production mode and i run setup:upgrade, The contents of the pub / static folder are deleted by themselves !

Comment: Every time you run `Setip:upgrade` you have to run `static-content:Deploy` in production i think you cannot change this phenomena

Comment: Watch this: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6426#issuecomment-434991404

Maybe I can be clearer.

Thank you!!